# Constructing palindrome from a list of words

Tags: c++, algorithm, search, palindrome

Recently I was looking through some interview questions, and found some interesting one:

You are given a list of word. Find if two words can be joined to-gather to form a palindrome. eg Consider a list {bat, tab, cat} Then bat and tab can be joined to gather to form a palindrome. 
Expecting a O(nk) solution where n = number of works and k is length

There can be multiple pairs, just return true if found one.

Also, in the comments one of the approaches was this:

1) Add the first word to the trie ( A B)
2) Take the second word (D E E D B A) and reverse it (A B D E E D)
3) See how many letters in the reversed word you can match in the trie (the first 2)
4) Take the rest of the string (D E E D) see if it is a palindrome if it is you are done return true
5) add the second word to the trie (D E E D B A)
6) go back to step 2 with the next word
7) when out of words return false

But in my opinion this is not an O(nk) solution.

Can anyone suggest a solution?? Or explain why the algorithm described above is O(nk)??

Comment: `k` is length of what? Are all words the same length?

Comment: k is the length of the longest word.

Comment: Do you really ask for the code, or just algorithm? Going for full c++ implementation is quite a bit.

Comment: no, just the algo, the steps

Comment: So why tag it with `c++` ?

Comment: in case of someone can perform an answer with it...

Comment: Not a C++ question. If you are asking for a C++ implementation then say so otherwise this is a generic algorithms question and you should remove the tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The algorithms is correct, or at least it gets quite close. There are minor technical issues. In step 4. one should save the proposition of a solution if it's better than the current one, and in step 7. return it, or say it was impossible to make a palindrome.

The main idea is to process words into cores and prefixes. If a core is a palindrome, then we need to match the prefix with other word. Trie serves as a "database" for processed strings, so with each new word, one can check all possible extensions. If words were kept separately one would need to compare prefixes of each word separately.

(*Edit: I think there still is a small loophole, in case there are two words in a trie which starts the same, and the incoming one would make a palindrome with the shorter one, but not the longer, but I won't go into details. Handling it would complicate the algo but wouldn't affect complexity.*)

It also is `O(n*k)`. Adding and checking a prefix vs a trie takes number of steps proportional to the number of characters. So in this case this is bound by `k`. Just like tree operations are `O(h)` where `h` is the height of the tree. So in conclusion:

1. `k` steps.
2. takes `k` steps.
3. also takes at most `k` steps.
4. also takes less than `k` steps but we can bound it by `k`.
5. also takes `k` steps.

Steps 2 to 5 are done `n-1` times.

Of course each step has a different dominant operation, so it is hard to specify the exact constant, but all of them are bound by `k` so the complexity is `O(c*(n-1)*k)` which essentially is `O(n*k)`.

Comment: 1. The issue you identify in your edit seems more than a small loophole to me: to handle it properly without changing the time complexity, you need to a way to perform *all possible* suffix-palindrome tests in O(k) total time -- i.e., you need to be able to test whether the suffix of the current word that starts at character i is a palindrome in O(1) amortised time per test.  It's certainly not obvious how to do that.

Comment: 2. Separately, step 3 only tests whether we have seen a word, *some prefix of which* would work with our current word.  I think step 3 needs to be changed to "See how many letters in the reversed word you can match in the trie, *when we only allow matches that end at a node that is the final character of some input word*."

Comment: Apparently I'm not allowed to write a comment explaining why I downvoted -- this seems a shame, as I'm always interested to know why when my answers are downvoted.

Comment: @j_random_hacker Well you did write an extensive comment. I didn't have enough time to answer it. I was wondering whether I should explain why I think it's possible to resolve the loophole without comprising complexity, because I didn't think anyone will find it interesting. I'll try to do it as an edit today.

Answer (score 0):

There's a really interesting discussion of this in an article from [Dr. Dobbs](http://www.drdobbs.com/architecture-and-design/adventures-in-palindromes/184405615%20Dr%20Dobbs), way back in 2004.  The full explanation is a little long, but the general idea is:

> Suppose you start with Lion, where the pivot is left of the actual word. I can calculate the center of the string, which is position two. The pivot is at zero, so the string is too heavy on the right, but at the moment, Lion qualifies as a partial palindrome. The "dot" at the pivot point matches the dot at the pivot point, so there is at least one correct character, albeit the same character. You now wish to prepend words that end with noil, attempting to convert the string to noil.Lion. I use  to mean any string of characters. If you're successful, then you need to locate words starting with  so that they can be appended to the string.

Note that he defines a partial palindrome as:

> A string is a partial palindrome if, working from the pivot point outwards, either the left or right end of the string is encountered before a mismatch occurs.